# How to load an image into canvas from a specific file folder using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, html5-canvas, loading

Here's my code. I can load an image successfully but I want to get the image from one file folder as an img src which is inside my asset folder.

```js
function LoadInput(){
  var canvas = document.getElementById("defaultCanvas0");
  var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
  
  var imgPos = {
    x: 1370,
    y: 626,
    width: 0,
    height: 0
  }
  
  var reader = new FileReader()
  var img = new Image()
  
  var loadImage = (e) =>{
    reader.onload = () =>{
      img.onload = () =>{
        ctx.drawImage(img,imgPos.width, imgPos.height, imgPos.x, imgPos.y);
      };
      
      img.src = reader.result;
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(e.target.files[0])
  };
  
  var imageLoader = document.getElementById("loadInput");
  imageLoader.addEventListener("change",loadImage);
}
```

Comment: Please don't share images of code: paste the actual code in the question itself in a code block instead.

Comment: What do you mean? you can't load a image from the clients computer/folder - it has to come from a server, most often you just do `img.src = '/assets/img/cat.png'`

Comment: btw, there is a better way to load images with `img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)` that don't involves async code and a FileReader that is slower